# type object 'UserProfile' has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, django-forms, django-views

My form is not submitting I am getting this error please help!!!
I think problem is in views.py.I am trying to solving this for a while

```
File "/home/letsperf/mydjangoprojects/form/basic/views.py", line 9, in signupview
if user_form.is_valid():
File "/home/letsperf/.conda/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 183, in is_valid
return self.is_bound and not self.errors
File "/home/letsperf/.conda/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 175, in errors
self.full_clean()
File "/home/letsperf/.conda/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 384, in full_clean
self._clean_fields()
File "/home/letsperf/.conda/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 405, in _clean_fields
value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
File "/home/letsperf/mydjangoprojects/form/basic/forms.py", line 24, in clean_email
email_qs = UserProfile.object.filter(email=email)
AttributeError: type object 'UserProfile' has no attribute 'object'
```

[03/Aug/2017 09:24:52] "POST /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 500 92520

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from basic.forms import UserProfileForm


# Create your views here.
def signupview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            password = user_form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            confirm_password = user_form.cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')
            user = UserProfileForm()
            user.set_password(password)
            user.set_password(confirm_password)
            user.save()

    return render(request, 'basic/register.html')
```

forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email address")
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = {'username', 'email', 'password', 'confirm_password'}

def clean_password(self, *args, **kwargs):
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password', None)
    confirm_password = self.cleaned_data.get('confirm_password', None)
    if password != confirm_password:
        raise forms.ValidationError(" password didn't match ")
    return super(UserProfile, self).clean_password(*args, **kwargs)

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    email_qs = UserProfile.object.filter(email=email)
    if email_qs.exist():
        raise forms.ValidationError("This Email has already exists")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a typo `UserProfile.objects.filter(email=email)`. This is `object` should be plural - `objects`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
email_qs = UserProfile.objects.filter(email=email)
```

Or another way:

```
email_qs = UserProfile.objects.get(email__iexact=email)
```

in this case if there is no matching you will get DoesNotExist Exception.